# How to make a rect svg element not escape the viewBox of the svg

Tags: javascript

I have an SVG

```
<svg id='mainSvg' viewBox='0 0 1920 1080'>

    <rect id='rectangle' x='800' y='800'/>

  </svg>
```

and I am moving the rectangle inside the SVG with javascript with left and right arrow keys and A and D keys.
that is working perfectly but I have a problem that the rectangle can go outside of the view-box of the SVG and I want the rectangle to stop when it touches the left or right corner. this is my code.

```
    function keyDown(event) {
  if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft' || event.key === 'a') {
    leftKey = true;
    aKey = true;
  } else if (event.key === 'ArrowRight' || event.key === 'd') {
    rightKey = true;
    dKey = true;
  }
}

function keyUp(event) {
  if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft' || event.key === 'a') {
    leftKey = false;
    aKey = false;
  } else if (event.key === 'ArrowRight' || event.key === 'd') {
    rightKey = false;
    dKey = false;
  }
}

function move() {
  let xPosition = parseInt(rectangle.getAttribute('x'));
  const movmentSpeed = 10;
  //if right arrow key,d  is pressed
  if (rightKey) {
    rectangle.setAttribute('x', xPosition + movmentSpeed);

      //if right arrow key,a  is pressed
  } else if (leftKey) {
    rectangle.setAttribute('x', xPosition - movmentSpeed)

    if(xPosition === 0){
      leftKey = false;  
    }

  }
  setTimeout(move, 10);
}
```

on the last function move() I tried saying `if(Xposition ===0){leftKey = false}` that works briefly but if the user keeps pressing the left arrow then the rectangle will start moving again and go out of the viewBox.

Also, the arrow keys have a value of false by default

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `Math.min(Math.max(xPosition+movmentSpeed, 0), svgWidth-rectangleWidth)` -- just get the element widths, you can handle that right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @NiettheDarkAbsol, Not sure about that, I am a still a noob in coding  could you elaborate please ?

Comment: You're trying to limit the output (the element's position) by restricting the input (the key-press state). Why not limit the output by... limiting the output?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  But how do i restrict the element position ? where do I have to implement the code you wrote on top...? Sorry again I am just a beginer :(

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Okay i got it to work, Thanks a ton, Could you please maybe explain a little bit more how this is working ?